# Net Core: Hold Multiple Class Types for Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a bunch of Class methods, which take a List of Image URLs, and place them into Tagbuilders, apply functions, etc. What is good way to accomodate flexible design, and should I use dependency injection? I only need ImageURL and Title.

**History:**

I conducted this initially. I am beginner and learned this is not loosely coupled well.

```
public void RunSomeprocess(List<string> ImageList)
{
....
```

Then someone came up with a Dictionary with Image Titles, and I changed into Dictionary to hold URL, and additional title

```
public void RunSomeprocess(Dictionary<string,string> ImageList)
{
....
```

Then people  came up with a class, one had caption, another had length/height. The only two columns I need are ImageSource and Title. What the best way to deal with this situation?

```
public class ImageListwithCaption
{
    string ImageSource {get;set;}
    string ImageTitle {get;set;}
    string ImageCaptionDescription {get;set;}


public class ImageListwithLengthHeight
{
    string ImageSource {get;set;}
    string ImageTitle {get;set;}
    int PixelWidth {get;set;}
    int PixelHeight{get;set;}
```

Comment: Would suggest generic method and have classes implement common interface.

Comment: Is there a reason to not just have one class with all the information?  Also I'd suggest changing the name of `ImageList` to something like `ImageData` as it's not actually a list of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have two classes with the same name in the same namespace.

You have a method which requires a `List` of Images, and these need to have a  `Source` and a `Title`. Your 'people' would like to have additional but different attributes on their Image classes. The way to handle this is to define a base class `Image` and the 'people' can create subclasses of that:

```
public class Image
{
    public string Source{ get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
}
public class ImageWithCaption : Image
{
    public string CaptionDescription{ get; set; }
}
public class ImageWithSize : Image
{
    public int PixelWidth{ get; set; }
    public int PixelHeight{ get; set; }
}
```

Now your method can accept an `IEnumerable` of `Image`, and callers of that method are free to pass in lists of `ImageWithSize` or `ImageWithCaption` or any others they dream up next week

```
public void RunSomeprocess(IEnumerable<Image> ImageList)
{
}
```

Comment: `List<T>` is not co-variant so you cannot pass a `List<ImageWithCaption>` to something that takes a `List<Image>`.  This will work if the OP can make the method take a `IEnumerable<Image>` as that is co-variant.  Specifically the issue is that if I have a `List<Image>` I should be able to insert a `ImageWithSize`, but if I was really passed a `List<ImageWIthCaption>` then that's not going to work.  On the other hand `IEnumerable<T>` only allows you to get items out so if I only expect to get `Image` it's ok if it's `ImageWithCaption`.

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right, I have updated my answer (and tested it this time!)

Comment: thanks my bad, forgot to rename the different classes above in question, I fixed it

Comment: So  does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary meets your requirements. You should stick with that until you need additional fields, i.e. width, height. At that point, you can refactor imagelist into its own model.

Comment: dictionary does not work,  I just discussed people are fitting additional items in class shown above, should I just force everyone to condense their class when they use method?

Comment: Yeah, only accept in the parameters what you need everything else is bloat.